# Show time series and mean for grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some data of different products and its corresponding sales with Datetime index. I managed to group them by product using:

```
grouped_df = data.loc[:, ['ProductID', 'Sales']].groupby('ProductID')

for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n\n")
```

And the output I got is:

```
              ProductID  Sales
Datetime                      
2014-03-31     1        2475.03
2014-09-27     1        10033.06
2015-02-03     1        5329.33   

              ProductID Sales
Datetime                    
2014-12-17     2        1960.0
2015-06-17     2        1400.0
2016-08-29     2        230.0 

.
.
.
```

I would like to be able to plot each grouped data on the same graph to show a time-series of sales.

I also want to get the monthly mean sales of each productID and plot them on a bar chart. I have tried re-sampling but it did not work out for me.

How do I go about doing the above?

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `seaborn.lineplot` [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

you can use

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y="Sales", hue = 'ProductID ',  data=data)
```

you don't even need to group them